# Estimation of the Bias

Tags: confidence-interval, bias

I have an estimator $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ of a quantity $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

The mean squared error

$$\mathrm{MSE} = \mathbb{E}\left[(\hat{\mathbf{x}} - \mathbf{x})^\intercal(\hat{\mathbf{x}} - \mathbf{x})\right]$$

can be decomposed in

$$\mathrm{MSE} = \underbrace{\mathrm{Tr}\mathrm{Cov}[\mathbf{\hat{x}}]}_\text{Variance} + \underbrace{\mathbb{E}[\hat{\mathbf{x}} - \mathbf{x}]^\intercal\mathbb{E}[\hat{\mathbf{x}} - \mathbf{x}]}_{\text{Bias}^2}$$
where $\mathrm{Tr}$ is the *trace*.

The first term can be referred to the classic variance of the estimator, while the second can be referred to the usual $\mathrm{Bias}^2$.

Now, I would like to approximate $\mathrm{Bias}^2$ via samples $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_i^A \sim \hat{\mathbf{x}}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_i^A \sim \hat{\mathbf{x}}$, independently generated.

$$ \mathbb{E}[\hat{\mathbf{x}} - \mathbf{x}]^\intercal\mathbb{E}[\hat{\mathbf{x}} - \mathbf{x}] \approx \left(\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N\hat{\mathbf{x}}_i^A - \mathbf{x}\right)^\intercal\left(\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N\hat{\mathbf{x}}_i^B - \mathbf{x}\right)$$

Now the question: how can I construct a confidence interval of the estimated bias? And how can I construct a confidence interval of the estimated variance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The bias for the estimator of $\mathbb E[x]$ is $\mathbb E[\hat x -x]. No square involved.

Comment: Sure. But the MSE = Bias^2 + Variance + Var[x], therefore I need to compute Bias^2

Comment: Estimation is made possible by adopting assumptions about the distribution of $\mathbf x.$  What are your assumptions?

Comment: $\mathbf{x}$ is fixed (is not a distribution). I suppose here to know (have access to) $\mathbf{x}$.